# iphone dev setting device orientation programmatically error

Tags: iphone

I am using this to set device orientation,

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

but it is throwing a warning:

> Implicit Conversion from enumeration type "UIInterfaceOrientation" to different enumeration type "UIPrintInfoOrientation"

Plus there is a problem which I assume is occurring due to that warning is that when I run the app, the simulator launches but remains black and app doesn't runs, and it says "Attaching to 'aap name'", and nothing happens, now I want to set device orientation for certain views please. guide me, is there any way or work around to do it?

Comment: Isn't UIDevice.orientation a read-only property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be using:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

to inform each of your app's view controllers of the accepted device orientation(s), e.g.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: Thanx EddieCatflap, i did as you suggested but nothing is happening, the result is the same as before, the simulator launches but app not, the screen of simulator remains dark, i dont know whats happening plz. guide coz i am stuck here. Saad

Comment: Hi Saad, it sounds like there is a larger scale problem causing your app not to launch successfully. When you try to run the app in the simulator does the debug console show any error messages that may help track down the problem?

Comment: Hi Saad, apologies for the belated reply. In your case I would start with a clean slate by performing a 'Product' -> 'Clean' within Xcode and a 'Reset Content and Settings...' within the iOS Simulator before attempting to run the app again.